# Get session ID and display details when logging in using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, using version 5.2. My login works well and redirects to dashboard page. I want to display some info in the dashboard page. I tried this code `auth()->user()->id` and this works well.

Here's my code below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\dashboardRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use Auth;


class dashboardRepository implements dashboardRepositoryInterface{

    protected $request;

    //Initialize request instance
    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;

    }


    //getDashboard View
    public function getCreate(){

        $users = \App\Users::where('id', $this->request->session()->get('id'))->get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address']);
        print_r($users); 
        return view('dashboard', 
        ['users' => $users]);
    }

}
```

I want that to display the information and it returns something like this when I `print_r` it out in `getCreate()` method:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

Here's my Blade view:

```
 <div class="col-md-12 ">
            @if(Auth::check())
                <h1>Welcome {{ Auth::user()->first_name }}!</h1>
            @endif
         </div>
         <div>
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <p>Your Profile Info: </p>
            <p>First Name:  {{ $user->first_name}}</p>
            <p>Last Name: {{ $user->last_name }}</p>
            <p>Email: {{ $user->email_address }}</p>
            @endforeach
         </div>
```

Comment: What is session key `id`?

Comment: What information you want to display? What error you are getting?

Comment: thanks guys i already solve this one

Comment: using this line of code here
 $users = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address']);
        return view('dashboard', 
        ['users' => $users]);